# Lazy-loading is not supported for detached entities EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, lazy-loading

I need help to my new project for learning. i am using linq and EF and getting data from db. but it's show subjected error my code are below

Class Have Many subjects : Class 1 have these Subjects list  English, Science , Mathematics 
ERROR:

> InvalidOperationException: Error generated for warning
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning':
>   An attempt was made to lazy-load navigation property 'ClassSubject' on
>   detached entity of type 'SubjectProxy'. Lazy-loading is not supported
>   for detached entities or entities that are loaded with
>   'AsNoTracking()'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by
>   passing event ID 'CoreEventId.DetachedLazyLoadingWarning' to the
>   'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' or
>   'AddDbContext'.
>   pri

```
vate readonly IGenericRepository<Subject> _subject;
        private readonly IGenericRepository<ClassSubject> _classSubject;
        public SubjectService(IGenericRepository<Subject> subject, IGenericRepository<ClassSubject> classSubject)
        {
            _subject = subject;
            _classSubject = classSubject;

        }
   public async Task<IEnumerable<ClassSubjectLib>> GetClassSubject()
    {
        var _dbs = await _classSubject.AllAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return _dbs.Select(x => new ClassSubjectLib
        {
            ClassDetailsId = Convert.ToString(x.ClassDetailsId),
            SubjectId = Convert.ToString(x.SubjectId),
            SubjectInfo = _subject.FindBy(s => s.SubjectId == x.SubjectId)



        });
    }
    public class ClassSubjectLib
    {    
        public int ClassSubjectId { get; set; }
        public string ClassDetailsId{ get; set; }
        public string SubjectId { get; set; }  
        public IEnumerable<Subject> SubjectInfo { get; set; }
    }




 public  class Subject
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR(100)")]
        public string SubjectName { get; set; }     
        public bool IsShow { get; set; }      

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }      
        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }      
        public virtual ICollection<ClassSubject> ClassSubject { get; set; }
    }



public class ClassSubject
    {       
        [Key]
        public int ClassSubjectId { get; set; }     
        public int ClassDetailsId { get; set; }      
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
        public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
        public virtual ClassDetails ClassDetails { get; set; }

    }
```

I need data Like

```
{
    "ClassSubjectId": 1,
    "ClassDetailsId": 1,
    "SubjectInfo": [{
        "SubjectName": "Abc",
        "SubjectId": 1
    }, {
        "SubjectName": "cfd",
        "SubjectId": 2
    }]
}
```

[Data of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Savuc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your useless extra repository layer and just do something like:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ClassSubjectLib>> GetClassSubject()
{
    return dbContext.Set<ClassSubject>()
                    .Select(x => new ClassSubjectLib
                         {
                            ClassDetailsId = Convert.ToString(x.ClassDetailsId),
                            SubjectId = Convert.ToString(x.SubjectId),
                            SubjectInfo = x.Subjects.ToList()

                         })
                    .ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says once you use `AsNoTracking()` lazy loading doesn't work since your navigation properties cannot be loaded anymore. Try removing `AsNoTracking()` from the query in the repository.